# "OAuthException - An unknown error has occurred" when commenting articles through the Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-oauth

We have been getting a new error in our Android app since beginning of October. We can reproduce it using curl, so have something changed regarding commenting articles through the API?

Here is an example of a call that fails using a valid access_token

```
curl.exe -k https://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=http://www.cnn.com 
-F  "access_token=AAACwlRNQEK4BAPr3ByJBVLN8uwDjDOk1JFhIWNB4xiH..." 
-F "message=Test from curl"
```

And the result is:

```
{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

I really hope someone can help out here as this is causing a lot of negative feedback in the Android Market :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Facebook SDK: 
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/209018432505064

Comment: I am facing the same issue, i was able to post a reply to the personal message but suddenly it has stopped working and giving me an Exception "(OAuthException - #1) (#1) An unknown error occurred".
Can you please help me out here?